# Assign array of string with the Length of a component

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How do I automatically assign the length of an array based on the length of another and push a string to it? Such that in for loop when I copy the string, it will automatically get copied to all the array strings.

```
public string[] ArrayOfStrings;
public Image[] images;

void Start()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < images.Length; i++)
    {
        ArrayOfStrings[i] = "Testing String";
    }
}
```

Comment: If your arrays have always the same value. You could perform this loop on editor time by using the `OnValidate()` unity method. It's a good idea to make computation on editor mode when it's possible. Don't forget to call `UnityEditor.EditorUtility.SetDirty(this)` after your change on the `OnValidation` method to force serialization of your gameobject.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ArrayOfStrings = new string[images.Length];
```

Then you can do the loop

```
for(int i = 0; i < ArrayOfStrings.Length; i++)
{
    ArrayOfStrings[i] = "Testing String";
}
```

Or you can use `List` and linq. For example :

```
public List<string> ArrayOfStrings;
public List<Image> Images;

void Start()
{
    ArrayOfStrings.AddRange(Images.Select(x => $"the text you want for {x}").ToList());
}
```

Comment: Yeah I was planning to go for List. Why is List better than array?

Comment: List can be extend easily because you don't have to specify the length of a list at instantiation. But it depend of what you want to do. Array can have better performance but if you don't make huge computation on a loop on update method. It would be acceptable to use list 99% of time. (Just my opinion)
And I like to use linq for list manipulation like select data with conditions or transform data and so one.

Comment: "_It would be acceptable to use list 99% of time_" Disagree; you would use `List<T>` only if you require a resizable collection. Behaviour is the primary consideration, not performance.

Comment: Or in other words, use the most restrictive type possible that satisfies your requirements.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay : Ok you make a point. This is why I wrote this is just my opinion. Because on my common usage of collection I often need resizable and easy to manipulation collection. I could not put word on my habit but your comment is perfect. Thank